# jQuery UI autocomplete values not getting selected after selection from mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have created a functionality of `autocomplete` using jQuery. It works perfectly fine but for example:

Whenever I type a text and and select the values from the list using mouse, it gets selected for the first time but if I again type and select the list. The values don't get selected.

Below is my code. Why is it not working?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#txtAssignVendor').autocomplete({
    source: AppConfig.PrefixURL + 'VendorData.ashx',
    position: {
        my: "left bottom",
        at: "left top",
    }
});});
```

### Update

And in Vendor.ashx file below is the code which I use

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
            List<string> VendorNames = new List<string>();
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnAPP_NEIQC_PLNG"].ConnectionString;

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PackageName"].ToString() + ".GET_VENDOR_NAME";
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_VENDORNAME", Value = term, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "TBL_DATA",
                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

               // da.Fill(dt);

                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    VendorNames.Add(dr["VENDORNAME"].ToString());
                    //VendorNames.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", dr["VENDOR_CODE"], dr["VENDOR_NAME"]));
                }
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(VendorNames));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add a working example in a JSFiddle or a Stack snippet?

Comment: @JamesCoyle: let me try. I will update it once done

Comment: Might be you have to re-register the mouse click event if you are repainting the dropdown UI for the second time rather than re-using it. Provided code is not enough to determine the problem. More information needed

Comment: @JamesCoyle: have a look https://jsfiddle.net/m4p5xkt8/2/ here it is working. but not with the one in my application

Comment: Seems to be working fine in that fiddle.

Comment: yes its working fine their.. but why not in my application. is that may be due to multiple js that I am using ?

Comment: without exposing the whole picture it will be very difficult to see why its not working. Do you have your app public on the internet?

Comment: @MerakMarey: no its not on public domain.. anything else than this , i would be happy to provide you

Comment: have a look at the updated code.

Comment: Hey when you type the second time, you get new search results - yes ?

Comment: @DavidBray : yes I get the search results but the selection doesn’t works

Comment: If you use a static array as the data source, does the same problem persist?

Comment: @SallyCJ : no, it works perfectly fine with static data as u can see in the fiddle

Comment: So from @SallyCJ and my comment we can deduce it's a problem with the dynamic data source...  doesn't autocomplete like the datasource to be [{"label":"John", "value":"John Doe"}] ... ?

Comment: I'd like to see a sample of what your Vendor.ashx returns

Comment: I think I believe what is going on. Are you calling that `$('#txtAssignVendor').autocomplete` multiple times? Load you page, and put a break point there..see if it hits that line more than once and let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide the expected JSON result from the request?

AS I don't have the JSON output, I have made a working example with an AJAX based autocomplete. You should type 3 characters to start the search.

```js
$( "#country" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/" + request.term,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function( resp ) {
          var data = []
          resp.forEach(d => {data.push(d.name)})
             response(data)
   }
  });
 },
 minLength: 3,
 select: function( event, ui ) {
  console.log( ui.item ?
   "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
   "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
 },
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="country" />
```

Comment: how can I test this ??

Comment: You can replace the `url` for yours. And maybe replace the `resp.forEach()` to process the data returned from your `url`. If you could provide the JSON response from your `url` I could help you with that.